# Server Error in '/' Application. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deploying

I'm new to MVC3. I've created a web application using MS tutorial. I succeeded to deploy the application to a third part server.

Steps taken by me to deploy the databases (Business and ASP membership databases).
for both databases I took a backup and restore it to the hosting server.

The business database works well, However, ASP membership is not and gave the subject question error.

I'm using VS 2012.

Comment: if you're not going to ask a question at least throw a question mark in there and make it look like you tried to ask a question

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please add some details to your question like the error you are getting, may be you can attach a screen shot of error message

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have copied all the stored procedures too, the membership database also contain some stored procedures and im 99% sure that you missed them while taking the back up.

also there is some data in some tables like in `aspnet_Applications` or in `aspnet_SchemaVersions` did you take the backup with data?

here is how the aspnet_Applications table should look like

[image]

and here is how the aspnet_SchemaVersions should look like

[image]